# Index out of range even when the value exists

Tags: python

I am trying to get the missing number in two lists. The input for example is 3, 0, and 1, and the expected output is 2.

In the end, list "a" has the value 2.
Below is the code and I'm getting index out of range.
But "a" has value in it.

```
class Solution:
    def missingNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        y=sorted(nums)
        my_list = [x for x in range(y[0],y[-1])]
        a=set(my_list).difference(y)
        b=list(a)[0]
        return b
    nums = [3,0,1]
    missingNumber(nums)
```

I'm not able to give the MVCE, because I am having the problem statement and the answer like this.
I do not need the answer to the code question, but to understand why this error is occurring.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*i did not find the answer in any of the related queries*" then please be explicit, which related Q/A have you read and how are they not relevant? Also explain what you are trying to achieve, what is passed as input and what would be the expected output. You should probably call `missingNumber([3,0,1])`

Comment: I have gone through the related questionare about the same "list out of index" errors but they are more inclined towards when they have not assigned any value or forgotten to use the .copy instances
I have updated the question with input and output

Comment: @user19077881 Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the code.

Comment: what if you have more than one missing number? or none? Can this happen?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code will result in a completely different error.

Comment: @mozway
Yes but for now , im not trying to solve the problem of the missing numbers but to simply trying to understand the error.
Why is it giving an index out of list error even when i have the value

Comment: `[3, 0, 1]` works fine; `[3, 2, 1]`, or `[3, 2]`, or just `[3]`, or `[3, 3, 3]` will show your error.

Comment: @ken Please find the MVCE as well

Comment: Well, if there is no missing value, `a` will be empty and `list(a)[0]` will raise an IndexError. You should use `my_list =list(range(y[0], y[-1]+1))`

Comment: Your mcve is invalid, because there is an import missing, and the class is never instantiated; calling `missingNumber(nums)` will yield a NameError. Just turn the method into a function and remove the typing stuff for an mcve.

Comment: Execute your mcve, *by itself*, a single script/file, to verify it actually works (because it doesn't).

Comment: @9769953 Please check now as to why my MCVE doesnt work

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like the first test case works (`[3, 0, 1]` gives `a = {2}`) but the second test case results in `a` being empty. What's the second test case?

Comment: @user2390182 I want to check the missing number in my "y" list. So the list need to be a=set(my_list).difference(y) right?

Comment: We don't see the call and class instantiation; we just see the same code in the screenshot as the code above; that doesn't help.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76405992/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one number missing, you can do this much simpler:

```
class Solution:
    def missingNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(nums)
        expected_sum = n * (n+1) // 2
        return expected_sum - sum(nums)
```

Your error comes from the second test case `[0, 1]`. If you add debug prints, you will find that the first test case does not produce the error, but the second one. You can see that the max number in the list is not necessarily the last number in the range that you have to check. Fixing your approach:

```
class Solution:
    def missingNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        # The range is always from 0 to len(nums) inclusively
        my_set = set(range(0, len(nums)+1))
        a = my_set.difference(nums)
        return list(a)[0]
```

Comment: This worked.
Thank you
 I just wanted to know why my code was giving an "index out of range error"

Comment: Added some explanation and fix for your approach.

Comment: Thank you. I realise where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in Python 3. It is returning 2 as output.

Try to print `missingNumber(3, 0, 1)`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).